# Redirecting urls in IIS 8.5

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, canonicalization

I'm using IIS 8.5 now and need to redirect from 
http://mydomain.de/produkte.asp?produkt=someID 
to
http://mydomain.de/produkte/someID.html

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One day work and here it is:

```
<rule name="Products" stopProcessing="true">
<match url="produkte\.asp" />
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^(.*)produkte\.asp\?produkt=(.*)$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="produkte/{C:2}.html" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
```